# Problems with htaccess, rewriting to files in directory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble rewriting a series of files in my directory with RewriteRules in `.htaccess`.

I have `index.php?page=page_name`

This one is working so far, and I've been successful with it.

```
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-a0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-a0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-a0-9-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [NC]
```

I've been able to do this for views, linked through the index.php file, which is the above named ones.

My challenge is linking files in **public_html/view/css/style.css** directory to make it look like **public_html/css/style.css**

This is what I've been trying so far, which isn't working:

```
#RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  /view/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

I have files in:

```
view/css
view/js
```

and some other directory.  I want them to look like:

```
domain_name.com/css/style.css
domain_name.com/js/style.css
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong and why this is not working.

Comment: You shouldn't need to rewrite your JS or CSS files. Just use absolute links or put a `/` before the path.

Comment: the idea is that, i don't want to reveal the location of the files, and not just the js & css files, but a couple of other form action files too.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The browser has to download the files to render the page so no matter what there will be access to those files. You will be able to see them in browser dev tools also. No point trying to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(js|css)/(.+)$  /view/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` sign; it turns the entire line into a comment and means your rule is never executed:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  /view/css/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$  /view/js/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. The files are in http://domain_name.com/views/css/style.css but i want to make it point to http://domain_name.com/css/style.css. i tried the above example, but it's not working

Comment: I think I may have misread your question. Just to be clear: do your rules actually contain the hash signs (`#`) like they do in your question? You do realize that a line starting with a `#` is a comment, meaning that it isn't processed as a rule at all, right? Try your original rule (`RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  /view/css/$1 [NC,L]`) without the hash.